# Highcharts graph series multiplies

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, highcharts, async.js, otrs

I'm using Knockout.js towards the OTRS REST api to generate graphs in 
Highcharts, but of some odd reason the series I'm adding to Highcharts
seems to multiplies itself.

This is my Knockout.js model:

```
function OTRSViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.api_url = 'https://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/REST-API';
    self.username = 'api_user';
    self.password = '';

    self.priorities = [
        'WHITE',
        'GREEN',
        'AMBER',
        'ORANGE',
        'RED'
    ];


    self.queues = [
        ‘Queue1’,
        ‘Queue2’,
        'Queue3'
    ];

    self.selectedQueues = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedPriorities = ko.observableArray();

    self.statsByQueueAndPriority = function() {
        var endpoint = '/Ticket/Search';
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(self.selectedQueues());

        // iterate over every queue
        async.each(self.selectedPriorities(), function(priority){
            var tmp = {};
            tmp.name = priority;
            tmp.data = [];

            // iterate over each priority
            async.each(self.selectedQueues(), function(queue){
                // otrs search parameters
                var api_data = {
                    'UserLogin': self.username,
                    'Password': self.password,
                    'Queues': queue,
                    'Limit': 10000,
                    'Priority': priority
                };

                 // do otrs request
                 $.ajax({
                    'url': self.api_url + endpoint,
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'data': JSON.stringify(api_data)
                })
                    .success(function(data) {
                        tmp.data.push(data.TicketID.length);
                        chart.addSeries(tmp);
                    });
            });
        });
    };
};
```

This is my html code:

```
<div id="graph-input" class="top-container">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Queue</h4>
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: queues, selectedOptions: selectedQueues" size="5" multiple="true">               </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Priority</h4>
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: priorities, selectedOptions: selectedPriorities" size="5" multiple="true"></select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="enable: selectedQueues, click: statsByQueueAndPriority">Generate Statistics</button>
    </form>
</div>
<hr/>

<div id="graph" style="min-width: 310px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var highchart_options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graph',
            type: 'bar'
    },
        title: {
            text: 'Queues - Priority'
        },
    };
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highchart_options);

    ko.applyBindings(new OTRSViewModel(), $('graph-input')[0]);

</script>
```

This results in the following graph:

[image: Generated Highcharts graphs]

As you can see the series seems to be multiplying themselves,
does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `$('graph-input')` typo?

Comment: In any case, there seems to be a lot going on in your question's code that does not seem to be relevant to thr problem (e.g. the tmpdata stuff, some of the chart settings, classes on elements, etc). If you make your repro more minimal, it's a lot easier (and pleasant) for us to help you.

Comment: `chart.addSeries(tmp);` you just push new Data into the Chart without removing the old ones?!?

Comment: There may be many reasons why you have so many series. For example: `async.each(self.selectedQueues(), function(queue){ ... }` <- is that `each` necessary? For me it looks like database is returning all queues anyway.. In my opinion, you should just make one AJAX call, with all params, instead of multiple of them and then adding async.